# How to convert string of the form {a=2 ,b=5} to JSON of the form {"a":2 , "b":5} in java?

Tags: java, json

I am getting result in the form {a=2 ,b=5} after spel expression evaluation.
I want to convert it to json.
How do I do it?
Please help!

Comment: Can't you at least do some research yourself before asking here?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research?(Hint: google is very helpful) This is not a coding service.

Comment: `{a=2 ,b=5}` isn't even valid JSON. How did you get that in the first place?

Comment: Please see: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) The solution isn't to convert the first string to the second - clearly, there's a bug in whatever code is producing `{a=2 ,b=5}` in the first place. Just fix the bug to generate the proper result from the outset.

Comment: @EJoshuaS, the input data is not JSON, OP wants to convert it _to_ JSON.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson True, but why can't the OP just generate it in JSON in the first place? Why serialize it like that at all if that's not the format he wants it in? I can't think of a valid use case for serializing it in the original format instead of just using JSON "directly."

Comment: @EJoshuaS, how should I know? Maybe because OP is using some `spel expression` (that I have no experience of)?

Comment: SPEL expression parser on parsing an espression from json gave me this output.
I want to convert this back to json.I want to know if there is a simpler way rather than parsing the whole of it as a string and replacing characters.
and yes I did google it.

Comment: I'm don't have experience in SPEL, but is there a way to make it give you JSON in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

here is your solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String something = "{a=2 ,b=5}";
    something = something.replace("{", "");
    something = something.replace("}", "");

    String[] pairs = something.split(",");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String pair : pairs) {
        list.add(pair);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String[] temp = list.get(i).split("=");
        temp[0] = "\"" + temp[0] + "\"";
        list.set(i, temp[0] + ":" + temp[1]);
    }
    String contents = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        contents = contents + ", " + list.get(i);
    }

    contents = contents.replaceFirst(", ", "");

    contents = "{" + contents + "}";

    System.out.println("Contents: " + contents);
}
```

And here is your result:

```
Contents: {"a":2 , "b":5}
```

Comment: I disagree with this. The fact that the string that the OP shows isn't even valid JSON suggests that there's a bug in whatever code is generating the string in the first place. He should just fix that rather than converting the string after the fact.